# Не понимаю как выравнивать контейнеры в одну строку. HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Куда только не пытался вставлять команды не выравнивается в одну строку.(По красной линии)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;

    font-size: 16px;
    color: #b6b6b6;
    line-height: 1.6;
}
*::after{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    margin: 0;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.header {
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(../Trademine/images/TradeMine_02.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: center;
}
header .logo {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
li {
    text-decoration: underline;
    list-style: none;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.inner {
    padding-top: 20px;
}
.nav_li {
    color: #b6b6b6;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
}
.nav_box {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@400;500;700;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>TradeMine - Гарант Сервис Minecraft</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="inner">
                <div class="logo">
                    <a href="#"><img src="../Trademine/images/logo.png" alt="Logo"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="nav_box">
                 <nav class="left__nav">
                    <a class="nav_li" href="#">Услуги</a>
                    <a class="nav_li" href="#">Аккаунты</a>
                </nav>
                <nav class="right__nav">
                    <a class="nav_li" href="#">Игровые Ресурсы</a>
                    <a class="nav_li" href="#">Вирты</a>
                </nav>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Должно получиться - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: как надо? не совсем понятно

Comment: для начала вставить в одну строку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы выровнять все блоки в одну линию, как выше вам сказали, нужно чтобы все элементы находились в одном блоке. И сделала вам правильную верстку.

```css
.container {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 1200px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .header {
        width: 100%;
        background-image: url(../Trademine/images/TradeMine_02.jpg);
        background-size: 100%;
        background-position: center;
    }

    .header .nav_li {
        padding: 0 10px;
    }

    li {
        text-decoration: none;
        list-style: none;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    ul {
        padding-left: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    a {
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .inner {
        padding-top: 20px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: center;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
```

```html
<header class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="inner">
                <ul class="left__nav">
                    <li><a class="nav_li" href="#">Услуги</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav_li" href="#">Аккаунты</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="logo">
                    <a href="#"><img src="../Trademine/images/logo.png" alt="Logo"></a>
                </div>
                <ul class="right__nav">
                    <li><a class="nav_li" href="#">Игровые Ресурсы</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav_li" href="#">Вирты</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
```